# Can I update an early Airport Time Capsule?

Tags: time-capsule

I have an Apple Time Capsule model A1254. It has a 1Tb drive. Is it possible to replace the drive with a larger capacity unit? It seems a shame to replace the whole unit. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody seems to know what the official drive size limits are, but I just connected an 18TB hardware RAID to a 1st generation Time Capsule, and it works. To duplicate my setup:

Configure a 4-drive hardware RAID using this enclosure:

https://www.newegg.com/sans-digital-tr4utbpn/p/N82E16816111149

(I used four 6TB drives and set it up as a RAID 5)

Connect the RAID enclosure to the SATA connector on the Time Capsule's logic board using this cable:

https://www.newegg.com/p/N82E16812119251?Item=N82E16812119251

This Time Capsule has pretty much been gutted over the years, so the only thing left is the logic board itself. It's powered by a 2A 5VDC external brick, WiFi and routing are disabled. It's just a hack NAS at this point...but it handles an 18TB drive.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be possible: Here is an ifixit.com [article](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/194014/Upgrade+drive+in+1st+Gen+TC+or+will+power+supply+fail).

In the comments there the following successful upgrades are mentioned:

- WD Red 3TB
- WD20EARS 2TB
- Seagate ST4000VN000 4TB

At youtube you'll find several movies demonstrating how to replace the HDD (e.g. [Apple Time Capsule Hard Drive Upgrade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhkKWRBaUME))

Check the power consumption specs of your new HDD as well as the comments about reliability issues of the power supply unit of the Gen 1 Time Capsules all over the net.

Comment: Thanks very much. Just what I needed to know, especially the possible pitfalls ( power, speed, reliability). I'd better think this over some more..

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to the videoclip on Youtube where a guy replaces his 1-st generation Time Capsule disk with a new disk with 8 Tb capacity.  And it works after formatting - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVwUMobLa_8